# Hide elements using Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and Angular Material. I want to hide elements inside elements like this.

```
<div id="abc">
   <div id="123">
      <p>Hello!</p>
   </div>
      <p>World</p>
</div>
<div id="def">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

I want to hide div block(id:123).I tried in this way.

```
var formElement = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('123');
formElement.style.display='block';
```

It gets an error saying **Cannot read property 'style' of null....** How can I solve this problem.

Comment: You can access the dom element using  `ViewChild` and `localvariable`

Answer (score 31):

This is not the way to hide elements in Angular. Bind your element's style attribute to a boolean, like this:

```
<form [style.display]="isVisible ? 'block' : 'none'">... contents</form>
```

And in your component class:

```
this.isVisible = false; // whenever you need to hide an element
```

Or you can use `*ngIf`:

```
<form *ngIf="isVisible">... contents</form>
```

Please, note that `*ngIf` removes the node and its children completely from the DOM tree completely if the conditions turns to `false`, and fully recreates them from scratch when the condition turns `true`.

Comment: Thanks! So is there any way to hide the element by using id instead using 'this.isVisible=false;'?

Comment: very clear and concise! thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

You can access the dom element using  `ViewChild` with #`localvariable` as shown here,

```
import {Component, NgModule,ViewChild,ElementRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div id="abc">
   <div #id id="123">
      <p>Hide!</p>
   </div>
      <p>World</p>
</div>
<div id="def">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

@ViewChild('id') el:ElementRef;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
     this.el.nativeElement.style.display='none';
     console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div #id>
      <p>Hide This!</p>
   </div>
<div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {    
@ViewChild('id') id:ElementRef;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit()
  {
     this.id.nativeElement.hidden=true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

The simplest way to hide elements using DOM is

```
document.getElementById('123').hidden = true;
```

in typescript.